# letters in consecutive numbers

Tags: mathematics, letters

Are there any consecutive integers which don't share letters when spelled out in English (e.g.**O**ne, tw**O**)? If not, can you construct a proof?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer:

> NO.

Proof:

- Firstly consider the early numbers with "irregular" words:

  > **o**ne, Tw**o**, Th**r**ee, Fou**r**, F**i**ve, S**i**x, Sev**e**n, **e**ight, nin**e**, t**e**n, **e**leven, tw**e**lve.
- Then the "teens" all share letters, ending with

  > ninetEen, twEnty.
- Then all the twenty-somethings share letters with each other, all the thirty-somethings with each other, etc. The only possible place to get two consecutive numbers not sharing letters is

  > a multiple of ten and the one just before it. And even that's not possible because they all contain "ty" in the number. Going from Ninety-nine to a huNdred is also fine, and then to a thousaNd, a millioN, a billioN, trillioN, etc.

> Even infiNity will be OK :-P

Comment: You can extend it through zero to the negative integers.

Comment: @Jaap Negative numbers are trivial: they all share the letters of MINUS :-D

Comment: Good answer. Your bold letters are missing for the alternate pairs though

Comment: @simonalexander2005 I didn't want to do everything in bold because then it wouldn't be immediately clear what was paired with what. So I alternated between bold and capital letters to mark out the matching pairs.

Comment: There's at least one point where the *N* portion of the proof fails. It's at 100 *9's* and a googol - but the *O's* cover for you

Comment: Or nine duotrigintillion, nine hundred ninety-nine untrigintillion, nine hundred ninety-nine trigintillion, nine hundred ninety-nine novemvigintillion, nine hundred ninety-nine octovigintillion, nine hundred ninety-nine septenvigintillion, nine hundred ninety-nine sexvigintillion, nine hundred ninety-nine quinvigintillion, nine hundred ninety-nine quattuorvigintillion, nine hundred ninety-nine trevigintillion, nine hundred ninety-nine duovigintillion [..too long for comment..] nine hundred ninety-nine and one googol

Comment: I think it's fascinating that English is the only language I can find with this feature.